# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, syntax-error

I am getting an error when running meteor.js. This is the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\ketan\Documents\Meteor> meteor run
C:\Users\ketan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ProjectContext._readResolverResultCache (C:\tools\project-context.js:605:16)
    at ProjectContext.reset (C:\tools\project-context.js:245:10)
    at new ProjectContext (C:\tools\project-context.js:60:8)
    at Command.doRunCommand [as func] (C:\tools\cli\commands.js:356:24)
    at C:\tools\cli\main.js:1528:15
```

I can't understand the error. Please tell me the solution for this.

*Note: My laptop shut down in the previous session of the meteor.*

Comment: Please copy-paste the "SyntaxError:" line to the post from the error message.

Comment: `Note: My laptop shut down in the previous session of the meteor.` please run `meteor reset` then `rm -rf ./node_modules` then `meteor npm install` and run your app again. Is the error resolved then?

Answer (score 2):

### The Solution

How I ultimately ended up fixing this was just by re-cloning the repository I was working on from GitHub - after this, my application ran fine.

NOTE: I've edited this answer because I originally thought [Jankaput's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3098783/jankapunkt) answer worked for me, but after digging a little further I found that it didn't.

### More Info

I ran into the same problem after a shutdown while a previous Meteor process was running.

For me, running `meteor reset` and re-installing `node_modules` seemed to prevent the mentioned error from happening, but when I ran the application, I noticed odd behavior from several different sections of the application (i.e. certain packages wouldn't work, some methods that normally run fine on startup threw errors, etc.)

This makes me think that some sort of project setting was corrupted due to the meteor server I was running ending abnormally when I force shut down my computer. I'm not sure why whatever setting was corrupted managed to stay that way across a `meteor reset` (since `meteor --help` specifies that it 'Resets the project state'), but the fact that a re-cloning work makes me think that it did.

Due to the fact that it seems like running `meteor reset` could allow some corrupted project settings to fly under the radar after this issue pops up, I personally feel that it's probably just best to re-clone your project if this happens to you, just to be sure that nothing about the project is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to me that you have a syntax error in a JSON file that is being read by the Meteor build tool. Do you have a `settings.json` file in use in your project? If so, check for trailing commas or keys missing double quotes as these are the most common errors introduced to a JSON file.

Comment: The erranous token should be visible in the error message in that case. I doubt it being a BOM mark.

Comment: Can you guide me to the location of the settings.json file? I can't find it.